# Is there a way to know which programs are currently running on my pc through python?

Tags: python, operating-system

I am writing a script, where I actually need to know if Microsoft Word is already running. I can check that as a person by, searching the task manager processes or of course just by looking in the taskbar, but **is there any function/method that returns currently running processes in my system?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `psutil` library:

```
pip install psutil
```

Now you can print running processes by iterating through them:

```
import psutil

# Iterate over all running process
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    try:
        # Get process name & pid from process object.
        processName = proc.name()
        processID = proc.pid
        print(processName , ' ::: ', processID)
    except (psutil.NoSuchProcess, psutil.AccessDenied, psutil.ZombieProcess):
        pass
```

And the output will be something like:

```
smss.exe  :::  448
notepad.exe  :::  488
WUDFHost.exe  :::  520
svchost.exe  :::  544
fontdrvhost.exe  :::  612
....
....
```

You can find more [here](https://thispointer.com/python-get-list-of-all-running-processes-and-sort-by-highest-memory-usage/).